# Performance issue in sub-menu of simple game causes isolated unresponsiveness for 1.5+ seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a game that allows for character selection, which is accessed through a button press from the main screen. This character selection sub menu is unresponsive for approximately 1.5 seconds after loading the menu. Specifically, the `next` button to start iterating through characters is unusable. No other aspects of the game suffer from this level of performance issue, so I believe it is isolated to my code in the character selection menu.

The character selection menu displays one character at a time (out of 5) and iterating with next/back methods is done with `switch`. This is handled within the `updateShowCharacter` method.

Full list of methods are as follows:
`init, next, back, select, show, hide, updateShowCharacter, updateButtonUnlockAndRestore`

I believe the error is isolated to `init` because once it is loaded and the `next` button becomes usable, performance is flawless. However, no amount of debugging has provided me with any indication of a problem besides user testing.

Can anyone see a problem that would cause a 1.5 second delay before the `next` button becomes active?

Full `init` method copied below:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.hidden = YES;
        moveNodeShow = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointZero duration:0.5];
        moveNodeHide = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(-[Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame, 0) duration:0.5];

        SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake([Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame, [Configurations sharedInstance].heightGame)];
        [background setPosition:CGPointMake([Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame/2, [Configurations sharedInstance].heightGame/2)];
        background.alpha = 0.9;
        [self addChild:background];

        btnExit = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[[Configurations sharedInstance]texture_button_exit]];
        btnExit.xScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnExit.yScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnExit.position = CGPointMake(btnExit.frame.size.width, [Configurations sharedInstance].heightGame - btnExit.frame.size.height);
        btnExit.name = @"Button Exit";
        [self addChild:btnExit];

        btnRestore = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[[Configurations sharedInstance]texture_button_restore]];
        btnRestore.xScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnRestore.yScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnRestore.position = CGPointMake([Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame - btnRestore.frame.size.width/2 - 10, [Configurations sharedInstance].heightGame - btnRestore.frame.size.height/2 - 10);
        btnRestore.name = @"Button Restore";
        [self addChild:btnRestore];

        btnUnlock = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[[Configurations sharedInstance]texture_button_unlock]];
        btnUnlock.xScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnUnlock.yScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnUnlock.position = CGPointMake([Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame/2, [Configurations sharedInstance].heightGame - btnUnlock.frame.size.height/2 - 10);
        btnUnlock.name = @"Button Unlock";
        [self addChild:btnUnlock];

        character = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[[Configurations sharedInstance]characterTextureWithType:[AppUserDefaults sharedInstance].getTypeHero]];
        character.xScale = (Configurations.sharedInstance.widthGame/4)/32;
        character.yScale = (Configurations.sharedInstance.widthGame/4)/32;
        character.position = CGPointMake([Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame/2, [Configurations sharedInstance].heightGame * 0.5);
        character.name = @"Show character";
        [self addChild:character];

        nameLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:[Configurations sharedInstance].fontName];
        nameLabel.text = @"SELECT";
        nameLabel.fontColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        nameLabel.fontSize = [Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame * 0.08;
        nameLabel.position = CGPointMake([Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame/2, character.position.y + character.frame.size.height * 0.75);
        nameLabel.zPosition = 2;
        [self addChild:nameLabel];

        btnSelect = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[Configurations sharedInstance].texture_button_select];
        btnSelect.xScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnSelect.yScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnSelect.position = CGPointMake([Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame/2,[Configurations sharedInstance].heightGame/4);
        btnSelect.name = @"Button Select";
        [self addChild: btnSelect];

        btnBack = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[Configurations sharedInstance].texture_button_back];
        btnBack.xScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnBack.yScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnBack.position = CGPointMake(btnSelect.position.x - btnSelect.size.width/2 - btnBack.size.width/4 - btnBack.size.width/2,btnSelect.position.y);
        btnBack.name = @"Button Back";
        [self addChild: btnBack];

        btnNext = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[Configurations sharedInstance].texture_button_next];
        btnNext.xScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnNext.yScale = [Configurations sharedInstance].scale_buttons;
        btnNext.position = CGPointMake(btnSelect.position.x + btnSelect.size.width/2 + btnNext.size.width/4 + btnNext.size.width/2,btnSelect.position.y);
        btnNext.name = @"Button Next";
        [self addChild: btnNext];

        _showCharacter = [[AppUserDefaults sharedInstance]getTypeHero];
        [self updateShowCharacter];
        if ([[AppUserDefaults sharedInstance]getGetProductsFinished] && [[AppUserDefaults sharedInstance]getGetProductsError] == nil) {
            unlockAllCharacters.hidden = YES;
            restorePurchases.hidden = YES;
        }else{
            unlockAllCharacters.hidden = NO;
            restorePurchases.hidden = NO;
        }
        lblPrice = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Alternate"];
        lblPrice.fontSize = [Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame * 0.05;
        lblPrice.position = CGPointMake(btnSelect.position.x, btnSelect.position.y + btnSelect.frame.size.height*0.75);
        lblPrice.fontColor = [UIColor blackColor];;
        lblPrice.text = @"0";
        lblPrice.zPosition = 3;
        [self addChild:lblPrice];
        lblPrice.hidden = YES;

        lblPriceUnlock = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"DIN Alternate"];
        lblPriceUnlock.fontSize = [Configurations sharedInstance].widthGame * 0.05;
        lblPriceUnlock.position = CGPointMake(btnUnlock.position.x, btnUnlock.position.y -btnUnlock.frame.size.height*0.75);
        lblPriceUnlock.fontColor = [UIColor blackColor];;
        lblPriceUnlock.text = @"0";
        lblPriceUnlock.zPosition = 3;
        [self addChild:lblPriceUnlock];
        lblPriceUnlock.hidden = YES;
        [self updateButtonUnlockAndRestore];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: What is this does ?`[[AppUserDefaultssharedInstance]getGetProductsFinished]`
Also the code is not Optimized at all,you are calling this method `[Configurations sharedInstance]` over and over again instead of caching it, however I doubt it is the main reason, please use instruments to profile where is your code fails

Comment: Characters are in-app purchases. `getGetProductsFinished` is a bool to determine if we have products to display to the user. Not sure how I would implement your caching suggestions, I'm a complete novice. I'm not sure of the acceptable way to share logs from Instruments, so please see attached Pastbin link. I've identified about 400ms in delay: http://pastebin.com/zUYaq5st

Comment: And how do you determine purchased products ? via internet connection ?
via userdefaults or some kind of data base?
About caching just  make `Configurations* confs = [Configurations sharedInstance];` in the beginning and then replace all the `[Configurations sharedInstance];` with `confs`

Answer (score 0):

The first rule of performance is to always measure before guessing. The Xcode Profiler (aka Instruments) will, more than likely, show you exactly where your performance issue is.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post (somewhat), I have attempted measurement with Instruments (I referred to it as "debugging" probably incorrectly) but I'm at a loss and I'll admit I'm a complete novice, well out of my depth. I'm not sure of the acceptable way to share logs from Instruments, so please see attached Pastbin link. I've identified about 400ms in delay: http://pastebin.com/zUYaq5st